# how to use tcpclient in ucspi-tcp package?

Tags: linux

Got confused about using tcpclient in ucspi-tcp package.

i am using ubuntu , and install ucspi-tcp like this:

```
apt install ucspi-tcp
```

and then i started a tcpserver :

```
tcpserver localhost 10000 tee -a /tmp/test
```

After tcpserver had started, i tried to use tcpclient to send message:

```
tcpclient localhost 10000 echo "hello, JOJO" >&7
```

According to the manpage of tcpclient, I thought maybe i should redirect output to fd 7.

> tcpclient  attempts  to  connect  to  a  TCP  server. If it is successful, it runs prog, with descriptor 6 reading from the network and descriptor 7 writing to the network.

However, i got this:

```
bash: 7: Bad file descriptor
```

How do I modify the command of tcpclient to send message?
Thanks for any reply ^^

BTW

if i use `nc`  instead

```
clay@CVN76:~$ nc localhost 10000
hello, JOJO
hello, JOJO
```

The content of the file *test* would be as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpclient` sets up the file descriptors *when it runs*.
Trying to do redirections in the shell that is invoking `tcpclient`, *before* `tcpclient` is even run, will of course not work.
There's no file descriptor #7 open at the point that such shell redirections are enacted.

Look at the `finger@`, `date@`, `http@`, and `who@` scripts that come in the package.
Notice how they make `tcpclient` chain load to a(nother) `sh`, which *then* does a shell redirection.

## Further reading

- https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ucspi-tcp/-/blob/master/finger@.sh

Comment: got it.  `tcpclient localhost 10000 sh  -c 'echo hello-world >&7'` works fine. thank you!